# How to do small Rating Bar in android studio?

Tags: android-layout

I'm working with android studio. I need scale down a ratingbar.
I had try use this: style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
but it doesn't work

```
<RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:numStars="5" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scaleX` and `scaleY` if you want to reduce the size of the rating bar like this:

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    />
```